# Call Method Expression with Pointer to Struct as Receiver

Tags: go, reflection

There is `func someFunc(v interface{}, fn interface{})` where `v` is a pointer to struct (say `*A`) and fn is a method expression (say `(*A).method()`). How to call `fn` with `v` as parameter (using `reflect`)?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do with `reflect.Value.Call()`, however it's pretty cumbersome, especially if you need to do something with the return value. But here's a basic example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Bar string
}

func concrete(foo *Foo) {
    fmt.Printf("Foo: %#v\n", foo)
}

func someFunc(v interface{}, fn interface{}) {

    f := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    arg := reflect.ValueOf(v)

    f.Call([]reflect.Value{arg})
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{"Bar"}
    someFunc(&foo, concrete)

}

// Output: Foo: &main.Foo{Bar:"Bar"}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ED6QdvENxti

If you want to call a method of a struct by name, we need to revise it just a bit:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar string
}

func (f *Foo) Concrete() {
    fmt.Printf("Foo: %#v\n", f)
}

func callByName(v interface{}, fn string) {
    arg := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    f := arg.MethodByName(fn)
    f.Call([]reflect.Value{})
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{"Bar"}
    callByName(&foo, "Concrete")

}
```

Notice that in this case the method value is already bound to the struct instance, so we don't need to pass it anything as an argument.

Comment: Didn't the op asks fn to be a method of the same type?

Comment: You can do that just the same IIRC, I'll revise my answer a bit

Comment: OP asks for methods with receiver

Comment: @aerokite This works because Method Expressions (methods with receivers) are actually just syntactic sugar for a function like sample `func(*A, int, string)` (for `(*A).fn(int, string)`).

Comment: @KavehShahbazian With interface and composition in mind, not quite.

Comment: @leafbebop See my revised answer. You can extract a method by name and then call it.

Comment: I was overthinking it and doing the wrong thing by trying to actually work with the pointer in the reflect package. It was unnecessary because it doesn't matter when using `reflect.ValueOf(...)`.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Your answer is perfect and exact.

Comment: @leafbebop That works only if you know the name of the method.

Comment: And this time it is using a string. I am not saying this is not good or anything, but somehow not to the exact question.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian What works only if I know the name of method?

Comment: @leafbebop I do not know exactly. But the answer (the first part) was what I asked and it works perfectly.

Comment: And I do not ask you to know exactly. Are you sure you are replying to the right person?

Comment: Seems like OP got the question a bit wrong and I got the answer a bit wrong but it was the same wrong? :)

Comment: @leafbebop I do not get the _wrong_ part! :) If the name was known at the time of coding, it would be possible to just use a dummy interface. If the method name was known as a string, it would be possible to find method by name (as described in the second part). Otherwise the first part is the answer.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian the first part requires you to change the code of the orignal type: remove a method and it would break and hinder **other** part of code which accept it as a non-empty interface or use it embedded.

Comment: @leafbebop The question is how to call `func someFunc(v interface{}, fn interface{})` where _all we know_ is v is a pointer to struct and `fn` is a method of `v`; is there other way to do so other than reflection in Go?

Comment: @KavehShahbazian No, there is not, and I said nothing about **not using it with reflection**, did I? What I oppose, is consindering change `func (foo *Foo) f() to `func f(foo *Foo)` trivial. Methods is not just a syntax sugar. Am I clear?

Comment: @leafbebop This is working on my machine the way described in the answer! So it might be a syntactic sugar in this one case! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164176/discussion-between-kaveh-shahbazian-and-leaf-bebop).

Answer (score -4):

So to the challenge of using reflect to call a method without knowing name and being a method of the same type, as op (orignally) addressed, I have come up with a very, very ugly and unsafe way.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func getFName(v reflect.Value) string {
    return runtime.FuncForPC(v.Pointer()).Name()
}

func callMethod(a,fn interface{}) {
    fname:=getFName(reflect.ValueOf(fn))
    parts:=strings.Split(fname,".")
    name:=strings.TrimSuffix(parts[len(parts)-1],"-fm")

    reflect.ValueOf(a).MethodByName(name).Call(nil)
}
func (s *a) Tst() {
    fmt.Println(s)
}

type a struct { p string }

func main() {

    x,y:=a{"Good"},a{"Bad"}

    callMethod(&x,y.Tst)

}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/QgrGhI5DC3p

I would like to know a better way that does not rely on how `runtime.FuncForPc` formats methods (which is not version-safe), but this is the best I have. Please do tell me any ideas to improve it.

Comment: I am more than happy to delete the answer if anyone can show a different approach.